# Generic Function and action/return depending on Type

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have a function which deserializes some custom serialization sent by an API.
I want to build a generic function so that the deserialized object is not of type `Object` but of the correct type.

The strings which contain the serialized object can be deserialized into one of the following types:

- A `String`,
- an `IList(Of String)`,
- an `IDictionnary(Of String)`,
- one of many `SomeNameContainer` classes, all derived from a
  `BaseContainer` class,
- an `IList(Of SomeNameContainer)`, or
- an `IDictionnary(Of SomeNameContainer)`.

I would like to have a single `Function Deserialize(Of T)(MyString as String) as T`.
Inside this function, I tried to run some `Select Case T: GetType(String):Etc` tests in order to separate the different actions to run on `MyString`, depending on the expected object to create from the deserialization.

For example, deserializing into a `SomeNameContainer` is normally done via another generic function: `Dim Deserialized as SomeNameContainer = GetFromContainer(SomeNameContainer)(MyString)`

However, I get quickly limited, mainly because:

1. I cannot return a `String` type, because it is unable to cast it
   into T.
2. `String` is a value type, whilst `SomeNameContainer` are classes. So it is not possible to add an `(Of T As {New})` constraint. Which means I am unable to do something like `Dim NameContainer as New T: If TypeOf NameContainer Is BaseContainer` in order to apply the same operation to all the classes derived from `BaseContainer`.

One track I have found is to use `CTypeDynamic(Of T)(obj as object)`, which casts at run-time. That might fix problem 1, but problem 2 is still on.

```
Function Deserialize(Of T)(MyString as String) as T

    Select Case GetType(T)

        Case GetType(String)
            Return SomeFunction(String) '<- Only run-time casting allowed: Return CTypeDynamic(Of String)(SomeFunction(String))

        Case GetType(IList(Of String)
            Return SomeOtherFunction(String)

        Case GetType(...)
            '...

        Case Else

            Dim MyContainer as New T '<- Not Allowed to use New

            if TypeOf MyContainer Is T then
                Return GetFromContainer(Of T)(String)
            else
                '...
            End If

    End Select

End Function
```

I could decide to split each Type into a separate function. I would like to avoid so that I do not end up with 6 functions. That is because I also need to run some other operations on the string before it is deserialized. For the story, the strings come under various encoding/encryption formats. So if I have 4 formats, that is now 4x6=24 functions I would need to deal with.

I would love to have the luxury of encapsulating all the decoding/deserialization into a single function: `Dim MyObject as Something = Deserialize(Of Something)(StringFromAPI, MyEncodingEnumOptions.Option42)`

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You should go with the separate methods. If there is some common functionality between them then just pull that out and put it into its own method can call that from each. By creating a generic method, you are saying that it can be called for ANY type, but your method doesn't work for most types.  You can use generic type constraints to limit what types it applies to but there's no commonality among acceptable types that you can use in a constraint in your case.

Comment: I am thinking of maybe having a few overloads. Never tried on generic functions,but your comment confirms my intuitions. I'll post something if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use late binding / runtime object initilization, using `Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)`. A typical switch over `T` would then look like:

```
Public Function GetDeserializedObject(Of T)(ByVal MyString As String) As T

    Select Case GetType(T)

        Case GetType(String)

            Return CTypeDynamic(MyString, GetType(T)) '<-- Runtime Casting

        Case Else

            If Not MyString.IsDeserializable Then Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("Unable to deserialize to a {0} object: The provided string is not valid.", GetType(T).ToString))

            Select Case GetType(T)

                Case GetType(IList(Of String))
                    Return CollectionString.ToStringList(MyString)

                Case Else

                    Dim MyReturn As T = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T) '<-- Object instantiation to the type provided at Runtim 

                    If TypeOf MyReturn Is BaseContainer Then '<-- Now we can use TypeOf ... Is ... which will return True for all Object derived from BaseContainer 
                        Return Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T), MyString)

                    ElseIf TypeOf MyReturn Is IList(Of BaseContainer) Then
                        Dim MyCollectionString As CollectionString = MyString
                        Return MyCollectionString.ExportToContainerList(MyReturn.GetType)

                    Else

                        Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("Unable to deserialize to a {0} object: This type of object is not supported.", GetType(T).ToString))

                    End If

            End Select

    End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Performing a specific action depending on the type of a specific variable: that feels similar to Overloading, except that here instead of performing the action based on the type of the input variables, it should be base on the type of the output variables.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to overload the TypeName of a generic function. For example, `Function MyFunction(Of T as New)(SomeParameter as String) as T` and `Function MyFunction(Of T as Structure)(SomeParameter as String) as T` cannot coexist in the same namespace.

An alternative is to pass the expected output type as an input argument, so that regular overloading can be performed: `Sub MyFunction(ByVal SomeParameter as String, ByRef OutputVar as SomeType)`. Each overload including a different `SomeType` TypeName.

The output of the "function" is stored into `OutputVar`, which is passed `ByRef` and retrieved after running the `Sub`:

```
Dim MyObject as Something = Deserialize(Of Something)(StringFromAPI, MyEncodingEnumOptions.Option42)
```

Becomes

```
Sub Deserialize(ByRef MyObject as String, ByVal MyString As String, ByVal EncodingOption As MyEncodingEnumOptions)
    MyString = SomeDecoding(MyString,  EncodingOption)
    MyObject = SomeFunction(MyString)
End Sub

Sub Deserialize(ByRef MyObject as IList(Of String), ByVal MyString As String, ByVal EncodingOption As MyEncodingEnumOptions)
    MyString = SomeDecoding(MyString, EncodingOption)    
    MyObject = SomeOtherFunction(MyString)
End Sub

'...

Dim MyObject as Something
Deserialize(MyObject, StringFromAPI, MyEncodingEnumOptions.Option42)
'Now MyObject has been filled with the relevant data.
```